# php separate same value into a group in a string

Tags: php

I have a list of numbers that's may in the format below:

- 1234
- 12341234
- 123412341234
- 123
- 123123
- 123123123
- 12345
- 1234512345

I need it to be separate into group for those repeatedly same, and count how many group of same repeat number in each list, for example:

- 12341234 will return as 2 group, 4 numbers for each
- 123123123 will return 3 group, 3 numbers for each
- 1234512345 will return 2 group, 5 number for each

and so on.

is that viable?

Comment: It's certainly viable, but as this is clearly a homework assignment please share what you've done so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
$int = 123123123;
$str = $int . '';
$sub = 3;
$substr = substr($str, 0, $sub);
$chuck_str = chunk_split($str, $sub, ',');
$res = explode(',', rtrim($chuck_str, ','));
print_r($res);
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet, but I need more dynamic way for `$sub = 3` part due to the provided list is not fixed for 3